# HTML5, "bypassing" localstorage settings

Tags: javascript, local-storage

In a web application I'm creating a lot of media is used. As such there's quite a strain if each time the page is loaded this media has to be loaded again. (And as the media isn't inside the page, but rather retrieved by means of websockets I doubt the browser will cache it).

As such to protect both the server & the client, and to prevent useless strain on networks I wish to "store" the media locally - and then simply load each time the  program is run. Now the big problem is, localstorage (which seems to be made for this) is very, very limited: 5Mb in firefox. That's by far not enough for the media my program will use (around 100Mb) - it's also weird to me as nowadays we have hard drives of several terrabytes?

Is there a manner to "ask" for more local storage (apart from telling people to fiddle with about:config or similar things). Or otherwise, can I download this media and then load this local data? (Can I KNOW where the user has downloaded the data without the user manually navigating to the data?)

Answer (score 1):

The newest browsers support, one way or another, an application cache. It is intended to allow offline access to the resources a web-application fetches from a server, and does not use the localStorage memory space.

http://html5doctor.com/go-offline-with-application-cache/

Comment: hmm that would work for "static" data, however what about the data I dynamically get through websockets? - The media isn't necessary to load all at once, as it's mainly background and should only be loaded near when people use it.